# IndexOf not finding value in array

Tags: google-apps-script

I have two variables, one holds a hard coded date and the other has an array with a single value (for testing) .   the value in the array matches the hard coded value yet I get a return of -1(no match).

```
var cur_date = new Date('7/31/2018') ;
var last_row_cur = sales_sheet.getRange(1,1,20,10).getCell(index+1,10).getValue();        
var date_array = sales_sheet.getRange(index,9,last_row_cur,1).getValues()[1]; 
var date_index = date_array.map(function(e) {return e[0]}).indexOf(cur_date);
```

the log results:
Cur_date = Tue Jul 31 00:00:00 GMT-05:00 2018

var_date_array = [Tue Jul 31 00:00:00 GMT-05:00 2018]

var_date_index = -1

I was hoping var_date_index would return 0 as is the only result in the array and the dates match.   I am guessing it has something to do with the [] but I am  new to this so not sure.   TIA

Comment: For what are you using `map` ?

Comment: I believe it is used to break 2d array into 1d.

Comment: But your date_array seems to be already 1D in log results. Try removing map.

Comment: My log results is after map

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compare two dates with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492994/compare-two-dates-with-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

I just tested your code and the outcome is that

```
 Logger.log(date_array)
```

returns

*“Tue Jul 31 00:00:00 GMT+02:00 2018”*

while

```
 Logger.log(date_array.map(function(e) {return e[0]}))
```

returns

*“T”*

```
date_array.map(function(e) {return e[0]})
```

does not give you your array element

`sales_sheet.getRange(index,9,last_row_cur,1).getValues()[0]`,

since the mapping function is trying to retrieve an array element from an array. But in your case

```
date_array
```

is an array element. You are actually trying to access an element of an element (and not of an array), this is what gives you the error.

If you just change your last line from

```
var date_index = date_array.map(function(e) {return e[0]}).indexOf(cur_date);
```

to

```
var date_index = date_array.indexOf(cur_date);
```

it will work.

However, if you want to use the mapping, then you should define date_array as:

```
var date_array = sales_sheet.getRange(index,9,last_row_cur,1).getValues();
```

Comment: `indexOf` uses strict equality comparison.  Objects (date) compared using strict equality `===` will always be false.

Comment: This is also an important issue.  `Utilities.formatDate(cur_date, timeZone, format)` can be used to convert the date to a string - to make it comparable.